# How to save Map<String,Object> from Flutter to Firestore

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add a map of String and obj to firestore, The main issue is I'cant add the whole map I tried to use for loop to add the whole map but it doesn't work. 
Any ideas.

```
 OrderItems.map(dynamic obj) {
this._itembarcode = obj["ItemBarCode"];
this._itemPic = obj["ItemPic"];
this._itemNameE = obj["itemNameE"];
this._itemDescription = obj["ItemsDescription"];
this._itemUnit = obj["ItemUnit"];
this._itemBrand = obj["ItemBrand"];
this._itemQTY = obj["ItemQTY"];
this._salesPrice = obj["SalesPrice"];
this._promotionPrice = obj["PromotionPrice"];
this._promotionpadge = obj["Promotionpadge"];
this._itemVATType = obj["ItemVATType"];
}


Future<List<OrderItems>> getCartItems() async {
return await DatabaseHelperOrder.internal().getCartItems().then((results) {
  resultItem = results;
  if (resultItem.length > 0) {
    timerFunction(context, 1, 10);
  } else {
    timerFunction(context, 2, 3);
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => CatalogueScreen()));
  }
});
}
```

.....
.....

```
Future addOrder() async {
Firestore.instance.collection('Orders').document('$orderID').setData({
  'UserID': this.userID,
  'UserName': this.userName,
  'Items': {
        'BarcodeNo': resultItem[0].barcode,
        'ItemNameE': resultItem[0].itemNameE,
        'salesPrice': resultItem[0].salesPrice,
        'itemQTY': resultItem[0].itemQTY,
        'PromotionPrice': resultItem[0].promotionPrice,
        'ItemUnit': resultItem[0].itemUnit,
        'ItemBrand': resultItem[0].itemBrand,
        'ItemDescription': resultItem[0].itemDescription,
        'ItemVATType': resultItem[0].itemVATType,
  }
}).then((val) {
}).catchError((e) {
  print(e);
});
}
```

In this way it only add the first index.

Comment: which errors do you see? It didnt work doesnt help us much to solve the problem.

Comment: There is no error, My main goal is to save the  full map to Firestore, I tried to use for loop (“ for (int i =0; i<= resultItem.length;i++”) but it save nothing.  The above code is only saving the first index “0”,

Comment: hey, did you solve this? Kindda having similar problems. Could it be it's because you're specifying the zeroth index and so it's only saving just that?